# Unable to perform Switch Card by Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was making a booking form in which it has two tab i.e Daily and Monthly
My Plan is switch form when click on daily and Monthly tab
But I have problem in JavaScript.

```js
var daily = $('.daily'),
    monthly= $('.monthly'),
    card1 = $('.card-box-main-1'),
    card2 = $('.card-box-main-2');
   function ifActive(elem)
   {
    if (elem.hasClass('active')) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
   }
function switchCards(){
daily.on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if (ifActive(monthly)){
       daily.addClass('active');
       monthly.removeClass('active');
       card1.removeClass('dailytab').addClass('monthlytab');
       card2.removeClass('monthlytab').addClass('dailytab animated bounceInRight');
}
}
);
monthly.on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if (ifActive(daily)) {
       daily.removeClass('active');
       monthly.addClass('active');
       card2.removeClass('dailytab').addClass('monthlytab');
       card1.removeClass('monthlytab').addClass('dailytab animated bounceInLeft');
}
});
}
switchCards();
```

Comment: Do you use JQuery in this code? `addClass()` and `removeClass()` are JQuery methods. So I expect daily to be something like `$( '.someSelector' )` ?

Comment: you want us to fix your bug? or do you have an actual question? if so we probably need more code...

Comment: yes i want to fix it . i have posted the full code..

Comment: why is your on click events wrapped in a function?

Comment: codes works properly .. i just have some minor mistakes....in selecting class and Id...thank you for your time..